# CSS: n-th child not working for background-image

Tags: html, css

I want to have different background images using the `nth-child` property in CSS. But I am getting the same image in each of the child elements.

```css
#main .container .row .col-md-5 .card .overflow-hidden .gradient {
    background-size: cover;
    height         : 15rem;
    transition     : transform 0.5s;
}

#main .container .row .col-md-5 .card .overflow-hidden .gradient:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(152, 102, 2, 0.8), rgba(90, 102, 2, 0.8)), url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/mountain-landscape-picture-id517188688?k=20&m=517188688&s=612x612&w=0&h=i38qBm2P-6V4vZVEaMy_TaTEaoCMkYhvLCysE7yJQ5Q=);
}

#main .container .row .col-md-5 .card .overflow-hidden .gradient:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(152, 102, 2, 0.8), rgba(90, 102, 2, 0.8)), url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498404781417-2b02e42ecd0d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTh8fGVwaWMlMjBuYXR1cmV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="main" class="c">
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row pt-5">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="card shadow-sm">
                    <div class="overflow-hidden">
                        <div class="gradient"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Header 1</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Content 1
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="card shadow-sm">
                    <div class="overflow-hidden">
                        <div class="gradient"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Header 1</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Content 1
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have already tried putting various combinations for calling out the `nth-child` but nothing seems to be working for me. This is my first encounter with `nth-child` property.

Comment: There aren't any `.gradient` elements that are 2nd nth-children of `.overflow-hidden` elements. Also, you don't need to reference every ancestor element in the DOM tree when writing CSS selectors. Can you not edit the HTML to add specific classes you can use for the backgrounds?

Comment: And even if there were, your second background-image is a link to a google search results redirect, not an image url.

Comment: @Sean The nth-child does not work with this as well - `#services .container .row .gradient:nth-child(1)`. Where `row` class does have 2 child `gradient` classes within it.

Comment: @Omid Fixed the image link, thanks.

Comment: I mean `#main` and not `#services`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nth-child` only works for elements that are adjacent siblings within a parent container. If you walk back up the tree, you need to find a common ancestor of both the `.gradient` elements. In this case it's going to be `.row` as you correctly identified in the comment, but that element actually has four children.

So to pick out the two divs in question you want `nth-child(2)` and `nth-child(3)`.

```css
#main .container .row .col-md-5 .card .overflow-hidden .gradient {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 15rem;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

#main .container .row .col-md-5:nth-child(2) .gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(152, 102, 2, 0.8), rgba(90, 102, 2, 0.8)), url(https://placedog.net/800);
}

#main .container .row .col-md-5:nth-child(3) .gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(152, 102, 2, 0.8), rgba(90, 102, 2, 0.8)), url(https://placedog.net/600);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="main" class="c">
  <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row pt-5">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
          <div class="overflow-hidden">
            <div class="gradient"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Header 1</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Content 1
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
          <div class="overflow-hidden">
            <div class="gradient"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Header 1</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Content 1
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Understood.!! One last query, why do we have 2 and 3 and not 1 and 2?

Comment: Because the common ancestor `.row` has four children, and the `.gradient` elements are inside the 2nd and 3rd child of that row. Does that help you? :)

Comment: Ohh okay, got it now !

Answer (score 0):

> #main .container .row .col-md-5 **:nth-child(2)** .card .overflow-hidden .gradient

> #main .container .row .col-md-5 **:nth-child(3)** .card .overflow-hidden .gradient

```css
#main .container .row .col-md-5 .card .overflow-hidden .gradient {
    background-size: cover;
    height         : 15rem;
    transition     : transform 0.5s;
}

#main .container .row .col-md-5:nth-child(2) .card .overflow-hidden .gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(152, 102, 2, 0.8), rgba(90, 102, 2, 0.8)), url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/mountain-landscape-picture-id517188688?k=20&m=517188688&s=612x612&w=0&h=i38qBm2P-6V4vZVEaMy_TaTEaoCMkYhvLCysE7yJQ5Q=);
}

#main .container .row .col-md-5:nth-child(3) .card .overflow-hidden .gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(152, 102, 2, 0.8), rgba(90, 102, 2, 0.8)), url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498404781417-2b02e42ecd0d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTh8fGVwaWMlMjBuYXR1cmV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="main" class="c">
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row pt-5">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="card shadow-sm">
                    <div class="overflow-hidden">
                        <div class="gradient"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Header 1</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Content 1
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="card shadow-sm">
                    <div class="overflow-hidden">
                        <div class="gradient"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Header 1</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Content 1
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant use nth-child for.gradient in this code.nth-child for more than one child elemets in one parent element!

Comment: Please revise to punctuate your sentences so you're easier to understand. There should be at least two up there.